# Please explain the solution to this?

Tags: mathematics, real

[image: puzzle]

1 set contains: 3, 2, 1

2nd set: 6, 6, 7

3rd set: 10, 9, ?

What is ?

Choose from: 7, 8, 11, 12, 13

Comment: You mentioned an image, so that brings the concern that we are missing some visual clues. Are the sets arranged in a specific way? Or are they just straight lines? The visual aspect may be key to understanding the question.

Comment: May be its 13. There are two sort of z shapes. One reversed, facing each other. The sum of each would be equal if ? is 13

Comment: Awesome. Seems like you're all good to go with your first post. Welcome to the Puzzling Stack Exchange! :)

Comment: Although that solution doesn't seem completely satisfactory

Comment: I just wanted to put some information from comments that were attached to a deleted answer. OP has confirmed (in a deleted answer) that the top right circle has a 6, 6, and 7. - Despite one of the numbers appearing blurred, the top right number IS NOT a 5. OP has confirmed (in comment below) that all the circles are the same size, although the numbers inside the circle may not be. The 3 in the top left and the rightmost 6 in the top right appear larger.

Comment: The circles are in fact the same size. I've just checked the original screen shot. Definitely not different

Comment: @user1849962 the circles are the same size, the numbers inside seem not to be, unless the picture posted is distorted in some way

Comment: It may be inaccurate to go off size anyway since 10 is a double digit number and will have to be shrunk regardless. Also, 3 of the 5 choices are double digit, which creates a similar problem.

Comment: Yes I think size is misleading

Comment: Do you have a way to test the answer, or do you only get 1 try?

Comment: @user1849962 but are the numbers, in fact, all the same size (excluding the 10)?

Comment: The three looks biggest, then the six (left one). The nine and ten look the same. Implying the ? would be in the bigger font if this is a sound line of thought

Comment: Three looks bigger rather - not biggest - I.e same size as other 6

Comment: No way of knowing for sure

Comment: @user1849962 you can also edit this post yourself to change things as needed. It's a community wiki, so no one really gets credit for it. It's just for everyone to put information they've gathered.

Comment: The answer should be 10!

Comment: The 6 looks bigger than the other numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is

> 11

Reason being

> if you take the sum of each circle you get 6, 19, and 19 + ?. If you add them together in pairs, you get 25, 38 + ?, and 25 + ?. 25 is a perfect square. If ? = 11, then you get 25, 36, and 49 for the sums, all perfect squares (and 5, 6, 7 which is in order and slightly comforting).

Comment: Seems plausible

Answer (score 3):

One thought I had, although I have no idea how it would lead to the solution, is that:

> All three large circles could actually be the same circle, which is concealed by a rotating disc with three holes.  So it would actually be like a clock face, with the numbers 9 2 6 _ 10 1 7 _ ? **3** **6** _ appearing in clockwise order, starting from the top.

Comment: I’m leaning towards that direction as well. It also makes me think we should work in **Z** / 12 **Z**, as on a clock. The musician in my ear also cry “serialism”, but I think that my be cultural bias. Still, though, in **Z** / 12 **Z**, if you take n(i) for i from 0 to 11 s.t. n(p) ≠ n(q) when p ≠ q and n(p) - n(p-1) ≠ n(q) - n(q-1) when 0 ≠ p ≠ q ≠ 0, then n(12) - n(0) = 6, which would explain the two 6s on the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Another vote for

> 13

I don't think we have enough numbers/circles to establish a satisfactory pattern, but this is what I went for.

> Look at the top left 3 numbers. It's like an arrow with the 3 pointing west. For the circle to its right (clockwise) it's like that arrow has rotated clockwise juuuust a little bit. Then the 3 is replaced by 6, the 2 by the other 6 and 1 by the 7. For the bottom circle you rotate that arrow a little bit again and you replace one 6 with a 9 and the other with 10. Therefore, the patterns are:
>
>  3 -> 6 -> 9 (+3)
>  2 -> 6 -> 10 (+4)
>  1 -> 7 -> ? (+6)

After posting I realised that

> my answer is effectively the same as Gordon's, because you increase the sum of each circle by 13 (3 + 4 + 6). So, we can't pool our answers to say 13 is more likely than other guesses.

Comment: This is the solution I came to, prior to reading it.

Comment: While I like the idea of the three circles rotating, but I think it lacks the “meta” aspect of the three “large” circles.

Comment: @Édouard I don't understand what meta aspect you're referring to. Did I miss some context or comment?

Comment: I think you should look into a similar relationship between the three “large” circles as well.

Comment: @Édouard I still don't follow. Can you maybe give an example? With 3 circles, there can be at most 3 relationships, i.e., A to B, B to C and A to C, two of which involve the missing element. I'd argue we don't have enough data to find only a single specific pattern that fits the solution, as demonstrated by various answers here.

Answer (score 1):

One plausible solution is:

> 13

Because:

> The sum of the first circle is 6, the sum of the second is 19, and with 13, the sum of the third is 32. In this case all three circles are in clockwise increasing order with an difference of 13
> 6 + 13 -> 19 + 13 -> 32

Comment: Well that's two decent answers now which undermines the quality of the puzzle. I think the perfect square answer is too "deep" to be tested. Usually the solution is quite simple. This could be it

Comment: @user1849962 I saw mensa and decided to make it complicated xD

Comment: @ChronoD yeah when I saw mensa, it made me think my answer was too easy haha

Answer (score 0):

May be it is

> 13

Reason

> There are two sort of z shapes. One reversed, facing each other. The sum of each would be equal if ? is 13